# Export PFX from Azure not including root authority in chain

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-keyvault, pfx

I'm trying to export a pfx SSL cert from an app service (ultimately key vault) on Azure.

I'm running the following PowerShell:

```
$pfxPath = "c:\temp\GoDaddy.pfx"
$vaultName = 'myleadsvault'
$secretName = 'redacteda187a2ae-1013-4e08-a4f2-32a68575a76b'
Login-AzureRmAccount
$cert = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $secretName
$pfxBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($cert.SecretValueText)
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\$secretName.pfx", $pfxBytes)
$certCollection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection
$certCollection.Import($pfxBytes,$null,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$protectedCertificateBytes = $certCollection.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, '')
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($pfxPath, $protectedCertificateBytes)
```

So my problem is the pfx is downloaded to my local computer but it doesn't have the root authority included in the chain.

It's a GoDaddy cert and the chain I downloaded begins at `GoDaddy Root Certificate Authority - G2` while the actual cert begins at `GoDaddy Class 2 Certification Authority`and then G2, etc.

I don't know if this is an issue downloading from Azure or I'm just not understanding how SSL works but the chain is different and wanted to know if anyone could shed any light.

Comment: G indicates the version/generation. What you got is a G2 Root CA.  Take a look at the repo : https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository and you can see the chain of trust.

Comment: @Roshith but it doesn't contain the root CA cert (Class 2)

Comment: G indicates the version/generation. What you got is a G2 Root CA.  Take a look at the repo: https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository chain of trust and you can see that both "GoDaddy Certificate Chain" and  "GoDaddy Certificate Chain - G2" has got the same class 2 CA Root , but different versions ; "GoDaddy Class 2 Certification Authority Root Certificate" and "GoDaddy Class 2 Certification Authority Root Certificate - G2". May be on the cert the the word class in not included for G2.

Comment: @Roshith so is it the same cert even though it has different names and different number of certificates in the chain. For example teh cert returned from the endpoint has 'Class 2' over G2 but the cert I downloaded through powershell starts at G2

Comment: Yes and No. They are not same certificates , but one is a newer version of the other.    As long as the chain of trust can be verified up to root CA , which can be G2 or the Class 2", you shouldn't face any issues.